# How to write typescript for reducers in redux?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript2.0

I am trying to write a type declaration for reducers in Redux. Defined type for initial state. By I got error like, cannot find name state. Here are the sample code I written.

```
export type Addresses = {
  zipcode?: string;
  country?: string;
};

export type IState = {
  addresses?: Addresses;
};


const initialState: IState = {
  addresses: []
};

const testReducer = (state: IState = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "TEST_ADDRESSESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        addresses: action.addresses
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default testReducer;
```

In the switch case, I am facing errors like

```
Cannot find 'state' and 'action'
```

How to fix those errors?

Comment: Object spread operator is not yet available in typescript 2.0. It'll be available as of typescript 2.1 (or currently you can use typescript@next)

Comment: @Dieterg Is there any other alternative than Object.assign()

Comment: Besides frameworks as immutableJS, nope :-)

Comment: To continue using the spread operator you can use babel to transpile your code. Example here - http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html.